# how to detect firstChange with signal input in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, signals

now in the old Angular code we were using

```
@Input() foo = '';

ngOnChanges(changes: Record<string, SimpleChange | undefined>): void {
  if (changes['foo']) {
    if (changes['foo'].firstChange) {
      // some logic for first change
      console.log('first change', changes['foo'].currentValue);
    } else {
      // another logic for 2+ changes
      console.log(
        '2+ changes',
        changes['foo'].previousValue,
        changes['foo'].currentValue
      );
    }
  }
}
```

how to achieve the same behavior using the new signal input and effect?

I have read that I can convert the signal to observable and use pairwise, but pairwise doesn't emit for first value at all

here is simple example to try it out https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ymnhaw?file=src%2Fcmp%2Fcmp.component.ts

why I'm asking this question? because in the [RFC for signal components](https://github.com/angular/angular/discussions/49682), it's mentioned that

1. Signal-based components will retain the following lifecycle methods `ngOnInit` and `ngOnDestroy` only
2. `ngOnChanges` - is used to observe changes to inputs. As inputs are signal-based, computed can be used to derive new values, or effect to react side-effectfully.

[image]

Comment: instead of `pairwise` maybe you could use `map` and convert to an object with a `firstChange` property: `map((value, i) => ({ value, firstChange: i === 0 }))` [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ymnhaw?file=src%2Fcmp%2Fcmp.component.ts)

Comment: ngOnChanges() works with signal inputs.

Comment: @BizzyBob but that way I lose access to the old value, I need both if it's the first change and what is the old value

Comment: @OZ_ yes it works, but they mentioned that the life cycle hooks will not be part of the future of Angular

Comment: @Robert they will provide an alternative, that's for sure. And a schematics to migrate the existing code.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/discussions/49682 here they mentioned that only `ngOnInit` and `ngOnDestroy` will retain while everything else including `ngOnChanges` won't exists

Comment: ngOnChanges - is used to observe changes to inputs. As inputs are signal-based, computed can be used to derive new values, or effect to react side-effectfully.

Comment: I have edited the question to add more details